# HTML open popup window without user click

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Is there solution to open popup window on web page if popup blocker is on, and user not click on something etc. link for opening. I make chatapp and i make private talk i new popup window, not modal window. If sender open popup and send message to receiver I want open popup on receiver side with that message. Problem is only opening popup window if popup blocker is on(on receiver side).

I know, the purpose of popup blocker is to block annoying, advertising pop-ups appearing in browser, but maybe exists some hack or something similar? :)

Thank you

Comment: Very hardly. If there were a hack, the manufacturers of popup blockers would fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Will the user spend a lot of time on the page, or do they keep it open in the background? If the user is doing things on your page, you could have a notification area that says "So and so sent you a message, click here to start chatting."

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such solution.

You should consider a tabbed interface, where each private chatroom is a new tab in the interface. You can freely open tabs in the interface since it's just a part of your page, and it's cleaner for the user.